# How do you use Python in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, python

I am creating an app in Android Studio (using Java). I have a separate Python component that I created to do some stuff in the app but I'm not sure how to use it within Android Studio.

I want to be able to use the Python code in my app and be able to test run the code within Android Studio.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What's the purpose of this "component"? and why is it so important to have them together?

Comment: The app itself uses computer vision to classify images. ML/CV is best coded in Python (which is what I used). I want to build a mobile app with UI and everything but when it comes to adding the computer vision component I'm not sure how to add it in since I don't know how to add Python into Android Studio :/

Comment: I'm afraid it is not that simple, once you uploaded your app to android it runs with java and there's no way you can execute python code, perhaps you could execute c/c++ and unix commands, but not python.